# sessionStorage not returning correct result in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I'm trying to enable and disable a checkbox on a keypress on my webpage. I'm trying to use sessionStorage to make it last between page refreshes but not between browser sessions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var set = sessionStorage.getItem('disable');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('disable') === null){
     $("#cblDoctors_3").prop('disabled', false);
  } else{
    $("#cblDoctors_3").prop('disabled', set);
  }
  console.log(set);
});

$("html").keypress(function( event ){
  if(event.which == 119){ //this is the 'w' key
      var box = $("#cblDoctors_3").prop('disabled');
      $("#cblDoctors_3").prop('disabled', !box);
      sessionStorage.removeItem('disable');
      sessionStorage.setItem('disable', !box);
      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('disable'));
  }
});
```

So everything works fine, the console logs the correct status of the storage item, but when the page reloads, once the session item is stored, the box never reactivates on page refresh even if it's supposed to. So let's say that the user 'enabled' the box after it was disabled, the console will log false, meaning: prop('disabled', false). This is the expected result. But when the page refreshes, despite the session item being false, the box will still be disabled, meaning that the page is interpreting prop('disabled', true) despite the session variable console logging 'false'. What am I missing?

Comment: Small point but `if (sessionStorage.getItem('disable') === null)` ...you already retrieved the session item on the previous line...surely `if (set === null)` would be more efficient?

Comment: i don't want it to last beyond the session, that's why i'm not using localStorage.

Comment: I think you need to convert the `set` to a boolean before you pass it to the .prop() command - when it comes out of session storage it's a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caveat here is that `Storage` (interface behind both LocalStorage and SessionStorage) only allows `DOMString` as values to be stored (when using `setItem()`). Quoting [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

> `storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`
>
> - `keyName` 
>     A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to create/update.
> - `keyValue` 
>     A DOMString containing the value you want to give the key you are creating/updating.

The same is with `getItem()` - it either returns `null`, if there's no item stored under the given key, or a `DOMString`.

So if you run it like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('disabled', false);
```

... it actually casts the boolean into DOMString. That's easy to check: just run...

```
console.log( typeof sessionStorage.getItem('disabled') );
```

... and lo and behold, here's `'string'` instead of expected `'boolean'`.

Now, `jQuery.prop` actually doesn't check the type of its argument when working with `disabled` property. And when it's a string `'false'`, it just casts it to Boolean to decide whether or not it needs to drop attribute or not. And, as you surely know, `Boolean('false') === true`.

What to do then? One possible approach is not storing the value at all - just clear the item when it's not needed. Another is storing an empty string (as it's the only string that casts to false). In this case, decision part is trivial:

```
if (event.which == 119) { //this is the 'w' key
  var isDisabled = $("#cblDoctors_3").prop('disabled');
  sessionStorage.setItem('disabled', isDisabled || '');
}

// ...
const isDisabled = Boolean( sessionStorage.getItem('disable') ); 
// it'll be false for both null and ''
$('#cblDoctors_3').prop('disabled', isDisabled);
```

Comment: so I ended up running off of the concept of this answer and simply checked the string value of my session variable. if it equaled the string of "false" or "true", i simply applied my logic to each case.